# Using a plugin from separate Gradle Script

Tags: gradle, plugins, build

I have been using a plugin to generate some documentation. When I place the code for it inside the build.gradle for each package it works perfectly.

However instead of having this plugin in multiple build.gradle files I want to place it in a separate gradle script to keep everything more central.

However when i do this I get an error of :

```
Plugin with id 'com.benjaminsproule.swagger' not found.
```

Despite the code being the exact same as when it is in the build.gradle file.

Here is the code to import the plugin and use it:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven {url "http://jcenter.bintray.com"}
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.benjaminsproule:swagger-gradle-plugin:0.0.8'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.benjaminsproule.swagger'

swagger {

apiSource {
    springmvc = false
    locations = ['package1']
    info {
        title = 'Package 1'
        version = 'v1'
        description = 'Documentation for Package 1'

    }
    swaggerDirectory = "${project.rootDir}/reports/Package1"
}
apiSource {
    springmvc = false
    locations = ['package2']
    info {
        title = 'Package 2'
        version = 'v1'
        description = 'Documentation for Package 2'

    }
    swaggerDirectory = "${project.rootDir}/reports/Package2"
}

}
```

So I want to move this all from build.gradle to a file called swagger.gradle, is this possible?

I also run the plugin using:

```
gradle swagger
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a solution myself, might be useful for anyone else who runs into this problem.

I created a Swagger.gradle file which contained the buildscript and the build.gradle then called in the plugin.

For Apply plugin I had to called directly the main class of the plugin.
Swagger.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven {url "http://jcenter.bintray.com"}
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.benjaminsproule:swagger-gradle-plugin:0.0.8'
}
}
apply plugin: com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.GradleSwaggerPlugin
```

Build.gradle

```
 apply from: "/scripts/Swagger.gradle"


swagger {

apiSource {
springmvc = false
locations = ['package1']
info {
    title = 'Package 1'
    version = 'v1'
    description = 'Documentation for Package 1'

}
swaggerDirectory = "${project.rootDir}/reports/Package1"
}
apiSource {
springmvc = false
locations = ['package2']
info {
    title = 'Package 2'
    version = 'v1'
    description = 'Documentation for Package 2'

}
swaggerDirectory = "${project.rootDir}/reports/Package2"
}

}
```

Credit to this Blog: http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2015/10/gradle-goodness-apply-external-script.html